# How can I give rogues opportunity in a different alignment system?

Tags: rogue, alignment

In my campaigns not all goblins are evil, not all lammasu are good, etc so killing sentient creatures on sight based on race is strongly discouraged. Well, sneaking up and sneak-attacking is a rogue shtick, and I'm asking how I can allow a rogue to play like a rogue?

Comment: What game are you playing? (That's a rogue's *combat* schtick in *some* games, but is not a rogue's *whole* schtick in *any* game or *every* game.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie As indicated in the tags, he's playing a game that has rogues, and as indicated in the question, he's playing one where they sneak attack things.

Comment: @DCShannon And how to elucidate what else rogues are good at without guessing will depend on what game they're playing. It's certainly possible to write a good answer to a vague question via skill or luck, but the point is not whether good answers are possible — the point is avoiding collecting fistfuls of answers that, due to vagueness, are unfortunately on-topic but useless to the *real* question. Remember, closing is for preventing poor answering, not a sanction against the question.

Comment: I'm reading this as you asking how rogues can still sneak attack given a more subtle alignment system. If you're asking something else, please clarify. If you're asking for other things rogues can do besides sneak attack, I agree that's likely system-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

As SevenSidedDie pointed out, 'sneak attack' is not a literal mechanic in all games, but many games have a rogue or rogue-like archetype, and they tend to be sneaky characters that kill people when they're not paying attention, so I think I know what you're asking.

### Just Slow Down

Give them the opportunity to gather more information about NPCs than simply their race. They can then sneak up and kill them if it's warranted.

Just because a rogue likes to sneak attack doesn't mean they need to do it the second they encounter somebody.

If this is actually a problem for you, then you might want to read this: [How do I get my PCs to not be a bunch of murderous cretins](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/how-do-i-get-my-pcs-to-not-be-a-bunch-of-murderous-cretins/8040#8040)?