# How do I stop murder hobos?

Tags: dnd-5e

So I recently started DMing for the first time at a school club. I was basically voluntold by the teacher, and have never even played D&D as a player before. So I read 70% of the *Player's Handbook* and watched some videos, etc.

I get into the first session, and all the players are murder hobos right off the bat, and I don't want to punish my players too severely because they are new, what do I do??

Comment: Your issue is a common one. In fact its basically a duplicate of the [highest voted question on our site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/how-do-i-get-my-pcs-to-not-be-a-bunch-of-murderous-cretins). I've closed it as a duplicate of that question for now. However if there are specifics of your situation you don't feel that question covers feel free to [edit] your question to include them and flag for re-opening. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Being Voluntold and then reading 70% of the PHB is a good start for new GMs though. Our community is the best when it can answer specific and narrow questions: You could tell us the age and number of the group, which might differentiate your question from the one that it was duped to, and you might explain how your D&D club works (e.g. do you have one session per adventure or are you campaign-running but in a club setting?